# How to print response.curlString in console with Swift without freeze xcode

Tags: printing

I use the command

```
print(response.curlString)
```

in my NetworkManager class to print a curl string in the Xcode consode.

I use this curl command to test requests sometimes.

But some requests upload images in String base64 format and this generates a huge string and because of that Xcode becomes very slow. The String printed in the console is huge and sometimes Xcode stop working.

Is it possible to restrict the response.curlString command to not print huge strings or something like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
print( response.curlString.prefix(800) )
```

The number 800 is an arbitrary number, but it's enough for me.